# Angular material error message is hidden behind the next row

Tags: angular, html, css, angular-material

I am using angular material for my application and I came across a problem, basically the error message is hidden behind the next input when the error message is too large:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="example-container">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Enter your email" [formControl]="email" required>
    <mat-error *ngIf="email.invalid">{{getErrorMessage()}}</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Enter your email">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

**TS:**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

/** @title Form field with error messages */
@Component({
  selector: 'form-field-error-example',
  templateUrl: 'form-field-error-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['form-field-error-example.css'],
})
export class FormFieldErrorExample {
  email = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]);

  getErrorMessage() {
    return this.email.hasError('required') ? 'You must enter a value You must enter a value You must enter a value You must enter a value You must enter a value You must enter a value You must enter a value You must enter a value You must enter a value You must enter a value You must enter a value You must enter a value You must enter a value You must enter a value You must enter a value You must enter a value You must enter a value You must enter a value You must enter a value You must enter a value You must enter a value You must enter a value You must enter a value You must enter a value ' :
        this.email.hasError('email') ? 'Not a valid email' :
            '';
  }
}
```

[image]

Really don't know how to solve this using the material pattern, or maybe using another approach, for instance pure css(overriding material classes or adding new classes - but still I don't know if this is a right thing to do)

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rzay8h?file=app%2Fform-field-error-example.ts)**

Answer (score 1):

With Angular v15's MDC-based form field, you can set the `subscriptSizing` input to `'dynamic'`. Then the form field will dynamically add the necessary space in case of an error. See the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/api#MatFormField) for more information.

Updated stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-74r7uy

For more information on the MDC migration, see this [guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/mdc-migration).

Answer (score 0):

This maybe of some help, it describes some best practices for form validation.

[Form validation best practices](https://medium.com/@andrew.burton/form-validation-best-practices-8e3bec7d0549)

As for your answer, there are no exposed attributes for the `<mat-error>` which you can set to make the error box size dynamic etc.

You will have to use a different approach, for eg: Hidding overflow and show a popup on hover.

Validation error messages should be concise, any extra data should be shown separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can add top margin to the next element, something like this

```
[ngClass]="{ 'mt-20': form.controls['password'].hasError('pattern') }"
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the `css` below to solve this problem:

```
.mat-form-field-subscript-wrapper{ position: static; }

.mat-form-field-underline{ position: static; }
```